# Simulating Horizontal Scrolling of GridView using Gallery but scrolling Tables not Images android

Tags: android

I've come to the conclusion there is no Horizontal Scrolling for gridView. The work-around solutions online are to use Gallery in a multi-row format.

However, from what I understand, Gallery requires image files. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

I want a work around that can scroll tables (aka a grid view) . I'm basically making a Calendar where I'd like to scroll horizontally. It doesn't have to be as fluid where scrolling  vertically shows each additional week that comes into view. Horizontal scrolling can simply scroll month by month.

Nevertheless, I'm wondering if there is some sort of work-around with Gallery? Or does Gallery absolutely require images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I'm a noob. Figured it out on my own. Here's [a link](http://www.programmingmobile.com/2011/08/android-tutorial-gallery-view-without.html) for people who want to learn how to do it with Gallery, but I just came across ViewPager which does the same and I believe my answer will be found there. Thanks!

Comment: Link for how to do it with a [viewpager](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging)